# Create JavaScript element to use in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a small JavaScript API for my homepage with jQuery.
At a point later in the code, I'm attaching an object containing css to an element via: $(element).css(theVariable);

The result should be equivalent to the following CSS code for example:

```css
h3 {
 background-color: rgb(0, 80, 0);
 background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0.75);
}
```

The reason is obviously to have a transparent color but also work in older versions of browsers which don't support "rgba()".

How would I fill my theVariable so the effect when calling css(theVariable) is the same as the css-code above?
I *cannot* use something like

```
theVariable = {};
theVariable['backgroundColor'] = 'rgb(0, 80, 0)';
theVariable['backgroundColor'] = 'rgba(0, 80, 0, 0,3)';
```

Since the RGBA value would always overwrite the RGB value.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with JSON, which is a text serialization of data.

Comment: @Matt Ball
Yes, you are right. Think i confused it with the java script objects

Comment: Try to chain both `.css()` calls

Comment: @kaaposc
Hmm, I would like to avoid that. The .css function is part of the API code while this creation part I'm having trouble with, is outside.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. I suggest modifying your API so that it either (a) uses stylesheets with rules, or (b) returns an array of CSS objects, and the caller can apply them all in order.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the opposite in your javascript.
As you don't know if the browser has support to *rgba*, you can do:

```
theVariable = {};
theVariable['backgroundColor'] = 'rgba(0, 80, 0, 0,3)';
if(!theVariable['backgroundColor']) // Browser without support will return undefined
  theVariable['backgroundColor'] = 'rgb(0, 80, 0)';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's doesn't work unfortunately (just tested).
This code only assigns strings to the variable. There's no CSS-inrepretation yet!

Comment: @DragonGamer consider a similar approach that uses [computed CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/754607/139010).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for various features that legacy browsers are lacking. Then in your case CSS would look something like this:

```
.no-rgba h3 {
    rgb(0, 80, 0);
}
.rgba h3 {
    rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaaposc/670ufr2s/).